# Mocking return value of a nested call in Python mock library

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

Brand new to this library

Here is the call stack of my mocked object

```
[call(),
 call('test'),
 call().instance('test'),
 call().instance().database('test'),
 call().instance().database().snapshot(),
 call().instance().database().snapshot().__enter__(),
 call().instance().database().snapshot().__enter__().execute_sql('SELECT * FROM users'),
 call().instance().database().snapshot().__exit__(None, None, None),
 call().instance().database().snapshot().__enter__().execute_sql().__iter__()]
```

Here is the code I have used

```
    @mock.patch('testmodule.Client')
    def test_read_with_query(self, mock_client):
        mock = mock_client()
        pipeline = TestPipeline()
        records = pipeline | ReadFromSpanner(TEST_PROJECT_ID, TEST_INSTANCE_ID, self.database_id).with_query('SELECT * FROM users')
        pipeline.run()
        print mock_client.mock_calls
        exit()
```

I want to mock this whole stack that eventually it gives me some fake data which I will provide as a return value.

The code being tested is

```
        spanner_client = Client(self.project_id)
        instance = spanner_client.instance(self.instance_id)
        database = instance.database(self.database_id)

        with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
            results = snapshot.execute_sql(self.query)
```

So my requirements is that the `results` variable should contain the data I will provide.

How can I provide a return value to such a nested calls

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create separate `MagicMock` instances for the `instance`, `database` and `snapshot` objects in the code under test. Use `return_value` to configure the return values of each method. Here is an example. I simplified the method under test to just be a free standing function called `mut`.

```
# test_module.py : the module under test
class Client:
    pass

def mut(project_id, instance_id, database_id, query):
    spanner_client = Client(project_id)
    instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id)
    database = instance.database(database_id)

    with database.snapshot() as snapshot:
        results = snapshot.execute_sql(query)
        return results

# test code (pytest)
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from unittest import mock

from test_module import mut

@mock.patch('test_module.Client')
def test_read_with_query(mock_client_class):
    mock_client = MagicMock()
    mock_instance = MagicMock()
    mock_database = MagicMock()
    mock_snapshot = MagicMock()
    expected = 'fake query results'

    mock_client_class.return_value = mock_client
    mock_client.instance.return_value = mock_instance
    mock_instance.database.return_value = mock_database
    mock_database.snapshot.return_value = mock_snapshot
    mock_snapshot.execute_sql.return_value = expected
    mock_snapshot.__enter__.return_value = mock_snapshot

    observed = mut(29, 42, 77, 'select *')

    mock_client_class.assert_called_once_with(29)
    mock_client.instance.assert_called_once_with(42)
    mock_instance.database.assert_called_once_with(77)
    mock_database.snapshot.assert_called_once_with()
    mock_snapshot.__enter__.assert_called_once_with()
    mock_snapshot.execute_sql.assert_called_once_with('select *')
    assert observed == expected
```

This test is kind of portly. Consider breaking it apart by using a fixture and a `before` function that sets up the mocks.

Answer (score 1):

Either set the value directly to your Mock instance (those *enters* and *exit* should have not seen) with:

```
mock.return_value.instance.return_value.database.return_value.snapshot.return_value.execute_sql.return_value = MY_MOCKED_DATA
```

or patch and set return_value to target method, something like:

```
@mock.patch('database_engine.execute_sql', return_value=MY_MOCKED_DATA)
```